# Webpack source maps imported object highlighting in chrome debugger

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, chrome-debugging

We're implementing webpack build tools into our SPA project (which is quite big).
We're using typescript and the target of bundle is ES6 and ES modules system.

My question is about source maps generated by webpack and their behavior in debbuger.

We want the original code in the source maps, so we set this in webpack.config.js:

```
devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'
```

In chrome debugger when i import any module i didn't get any hint/information/preview about it.
In example below imported class Bar is not recognized by either the debugger (cursor hint) or the console (Reference Error).

[image: Example gif]

Is this behavior normal? Is any possibility to configure webpack to produce source maps with information about modules? Is our webpack/tsconfig configuration wrong?